# Question related to amsart

Tags: amsart

I'm using the following codes:

```
       \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsart}
          %------------------------------------------------------------
      \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
    \usepackage{color}
     \usepackage{url}

     %------------------------------------------------------------
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %------------------------------------------------------------
   \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
   % ------------------------------------------------------------
     \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
  \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
  \newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
  \newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
  \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
  \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
  \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
   \newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
   \newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
   \numberwithin{equation}{section}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%% hyperref %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}

  \begin{document}
 \title[Paper1]{Paper1}

\author[First author, Second author] {First author$^{1}$,  Second 
  author$^{2}$}

 \address{$^{1}$ University 1.}
 \email{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.84}{first@gmail.com}}
\address{$^{2}$ Sfax University 2.}
 \email{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.84}{first@hotmail.com}}

 \subjclass[2010]{46C05, 47A05}

   \keywords{operator, spectrum.}
   \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
   In this article, we ..
   \end{abstract}

  \section{One}

  \begin{thebibliography}{10} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
  \footnotesize

  \bibitem{acg1}{G. Corach,} {Partial isometries,} Linear Algebra Appl.

  \end{thebibliography}
  \end{document}
```

> I hope to get after compilation a title and the name of authors in lowercase letters and not in capital letters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the change you request is most easily done with patches to `amsart.cls`.
(i've removed a lot of code that isn't needed for this example.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\maketitle
  {\uppercasenonmath\shorttitle}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd\maketitle
  {\@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}
  {\the\toks@}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd\@settitle
  {\uppercasenonmath\@title}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd\@setauthors
  {\MakeUppercase{\authors}}
  {\authors}
  {}{}
\makeatother

          %------------------------------------------------------------
    \usepackage{color}
     \usepackage{url}

     %------------------------------------------------------------
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %------------------------------------------------------------
   \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
   % ------------------------------------------------------------
   \numberwithin{equation}{section}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%% hyperref %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}

  \begin{document}
 \title[Paper1]{Paper1}

\author[First author, Second author] {First author$^{1}$,  Second 
  author$^{2}$}

 \address{$^{1}$ University 1.}
 \email{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.84}{first@gmail.com}}
\address{$^{2}$ Sfax University 2.}
 \email{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.84}{first@hotmail.com}}

 \subjclass[2010]{46C05, 47A05}

   \keywords{operator, spectrum.}
   \maketitle
  \begin{abstract}
   In this article, we ..
   \end{abstract}

  \section{One}

  \begin{thebibliography}{10} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
  \footnotesize

  \bibitem{acg1}{G. Corach,} {Partial isometries,} Linear Algebra Appl.

  \end{thebibliography}
  \end{document}
```

the first two patches will remove uppercasing from the running heads.
the third and fourth patches will remove uppercasing from the title and authors,
respectively.  only the first page is shown in the attached output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope also the tilte of the paper in every pages and the name of authors in every pages will be  in lowercase letters and not in capital letters.

Comment: Please add `  \newpage` after `  \section{One}` and make compilation you will see in page 2 in the bottom ''2 FIRST AUTHOR, SECOND AUTHOR'' .But I hope to get in the bottom of every pages like this ''First Author, Second Author''. For example also in page 3  I get ''PAPER1 3'' but I hope to get ''Paper1 3''.. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Student -- will add code to fix running heads.  but you should have specified in your question that you also wanted those changed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your greatful answer. For a mathematical paper, is the following size good? Thanks a lot:    `\usepackage{geometry}`
   `\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}`

Comment: i really can't say what a "good" size is.  `amsart` and the other ams document classes apply what is traditional for the ams publishing history.  other publishers have other traditions.  and individual mathematicians have their own opinions.  i can say, however, that `amsart` is not really meant to be modified using the `geometry` package.